# Using Meteor what is the JS equivelent of {{{member}}}

Tags: mongodb, events, meteor

I have a meteor helper that uses a reactive variable in a find to get a unique document using an id. My item button template looks like this:

```
<template name = "itemButton" >
    <div class = "itemButton" name = {{_id}}>
        {{{title}}}
    </div>
</template>
```

using a reactive variable:

```
Template.landing.onCreated(function _OnCreated() {
    this.f = new ReactiveVar();
    this.f.set(false);
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe("Feed");
});
```

now I have a method in a template several itemButton.

```
Template.landing.events({
    'click .itemButton' : function(event, template){
        alert(event.target.name);
        template.f.set(event.target.name);
    }
});
```

and I would like to use that name in a helper that would use this value as the _id.

```
Template.landing.helpers({
    "GetFocus": function(){
        alert(Template.instance().f.get()); // alerts undefined...
        return(items.find({'_id':Template.instance().f.get()}));
    }
});
```

So where I expect GetFocus to give me the document that generated the button I don't seem to be so lucky. Let me know if I can provide any additional clarification, and as always your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where I have template.f.set(event.target.name); I needed `template.f.set(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id'));` where the html uses data-id instead of name.